# Не работает UPDATE mysql

Tags: mysql, update

Нужно сделать update в таблице Vakansia.
Вот мой код на update:

```
update Vakansia set nazva_pidpryemstva = 'SoftServe' where vakansia_id = '5';
```

Есть error 1241:

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Вот код создания самой таблицы Vakansia:

```
create table Vakansia (
    vakansia_id int not null auto_increment,
    nazva_pidpryemstva varchar (255),
    posada varchar (255),
    dohid int,
    primary key(vakansia_id),
    vymogy_id int not null,
    foreign key(vymogy_id) references Vymogy(vymogy_id)
);
```

*Можете подсказать в чем проблема, толком ничего не нашел.*

Comment: мне кажется проблема не тут, а в запросе SELECT, которого тут не представлено

Comment: У меня есть запрос `select * from Vakansia` и `UPDATE birzha_praci_remake.Vakansia SET nazva_pidpryemstva = SoftServe WHERE (vakansia_id = 5);` - Строка на обновление ячейки.

Comment: уберите круглые скобки в UPDATE

Comment: убрал, все равно такой же error.

Comment: не может быть такого. нужно SoftServe  Обернуть в одинарные кавычки и скобки круглые убрать..... самое интересное, в самом вопросе вы написали верно, а вот в комментах пишите не так))

Comment: вот мой запрос который есть сейчас UPDATE Vakansia SET nazva_pidpryemstva='SoftServe' WHERE vakansia_id=5; | Все равно тот же ерор

Comment: а если nazva_pidpryemstva и vakansia_id  обернуть в обратные кавычки?  в такие `\`` (где буква ё)

Comment: тот же error 1241..

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/baQFbOx5VLHAS1Fkh7uGHQ?language=mysql ваши запросы рабочие. Не знаю где у вас ошибка, но точно не там, где вы считаете

Comment: в той ссылке что вы скинули, при создании таблицы вы убрали vymogy_id как foreign key

Comment: потому что вы не привели запрос создания таблицы Vymogy. Но на вашу ошибку отсутствие или присутствие этой строки никак не повлияет

Comment: так потому что здесь таблица vymogy непричем, здесь update только с таблицей vakansia

Comment: Вот именно поэтому я и убрал ту строку. Зачем вы написали комментарий, хотя сами понимаете зачем я выкинул ту строку, мне совершенно непонятно

Comment: Спасибо что подсказали что проблема не в update, но мне не понятно зачем вы мне скинули эту ссылку с онлайн компилятором. Vymogy_id в моей бд нужен как foreign key так как он связывает и другие таблицы которые у меня есть. Таблица Vakansia одна из всех таблиц. Если это как то очень важно что я не сказал что есть другие таблицы то простите, но после всех манипуляций error так и не пропадает.

Comment: Вам стОит создать [создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ..... с созданием таблиц, данными и запросом, который выдаёт ошибку. В ином случае всё это гадание на кофейной гуще. И, как уже сказали, текущий запрос рабочий.  Так что вам просто необходимо предоставить **ВСЕ** данные по проблеме

Comment: хорошо, сейчас переделаю.